# How to write a loop in R that testing more than one parameters at a time?

Tags: r, loops

I wrote the following loop to select the best df, x, so that I can get the lowest AIC for the lm model.

```
aic<-rep(NA,20) 
for(i in 1:20){
cb1 <- crossbasis(AFH6, lag=24, argvar=list(fun="ns",df=8, cen=200), arglag=list(knots= logknots(24, 3)))
cb2 <- crossbasis(OutT, lag=24, argvar=list(fun="poly", degree=3, cen=12.28), arglag=list(knots= logknots(24, 3)))
cb3 <- crossbasis(OutRH, lag=24, argvar=list(fun="poly", degree=3, cen=68.5), arglag=list(knots= logknots(24, 3)))
aic[i]<-AIC(lm(NH3cH6~cb1+cb2+cb3+ns(DenH6,i)+ns(HenageH6,6)+ns(MweightH6,7)+ns(Time,5)+as.factor(LightH6)+ as.factor(MoltH6)))}
```

My question is: How to write a loop that testing more than one parameters (i,j,k)at a time? 
For example, I want to test

```
lm( NH3cH6 ~ cb1+cb2+cb3+ns(DenH6,i)+ns(HenageH6,j)+ns(MweightH6,k)+ns(Time,5)+as.factor(LightH6)+ as.factor(MoltH6)
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Maybe use a triple loop and store the results in a three dimensional array?

Comment: you might want to consider the `gam()` function from the `mgcv()` package, which will automatically adjust the degree of complexity of the smooth terms (which would be expressed via `s()` rather than `ns()` to maximize the generalized cross-validation score (nearly identical to minimizing AIC)

Comment: Yep, I'd like to try but I don't know how to write the code.... @flodel